# How much should answers be the same before they should be deleted as exact duplicates?

Tags: discussion

[Not enough pylons!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15190/not-enough-pylons/15199?noredirect=1#comment46873_15199)

leoll2 gave an answer to cut the pylons in half vertically. I gave an answer to cut them in half horizontally. Now, the person who created the question is pressuring me to delete my answer because according to him, it's a duplicate of another answer. However, I don't think it's enough of a duplicate. I also think it's against the rules of the SE network to delete an answer after it's been downvoted and replied to. I know I got into problems on the Physics.SE network for similar reasons.

So, is this a duplicate of another answer?

Comment: I am not aware of an SE-wide policy (or a policy on puzzling) against deleting answers with comments and/or downvotes. If there is such a policy, can someone provide a link to a relevant post on meta?

Comment: @JulianRosen I explained my reasoning in a comment to the answer by rand al'thor. Basically, deleting answers (and questions) counts against you for reasons of determining posting quality, which in turn can give you a question or answer ban if it's low enough. Since there are long-term consequences in deleting answers and questions, I assumed that this was against  a rule somehow.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it's really more of a comment than an answer. I'll just say that "it's against the rules of the SE network to delete an answer after it's been downvoted and replied to" is completely incorrect: answers get deleted all the time on SE, *especially* once they've been downvoted (because delete-worthy is nearly always also downvote-worthy) and replied to (because it's nice to explain to the poster what's wrong with their post and why it's been deleted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when two answers are exactly the same, and the time gap between their posting is indicatively greater than 5 minutes, the newest one gets removed.
In this case, the answers were slightly different, so your shouldn't be considered a duplicate, imo.
Anyway, the author insisted on another fact: "If his supervisor sees that Bob is not following protocol of using proper pylons, he will surely be fired!".
Apparently, your answer violates the OP assumptions, that's why he asked you to remove your post, probably.